# How to blur part of the underlying image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, interface-design

I am a newbie in photoshop and learning it all by myself, recently I came across of this image and tried to recreate the effect (I used another image though). What I did: 
1. Loaded the image on one layer
2. With the Marquee tool I selected bottom part of the image and layered via copy in a new layer
3. I converted it to a smart object
4. I applied lens blur to to the layer

here is the link: (Method 3: Blur the image)
https://medium.com/@erikdkennedy/7-rules-for-creating-gorgeous-ui-part-2-430de537ba96#.39hutajug

Is the method that I used correct? Or can anybody suggest a better one?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds ok to me!

Comment: If it looks how you want it to and it was easy enough to do then that's all you need. There's generally no one correct way of doing anything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I would go about doing it would be the following:

Take your clear image and duplicate the layer.

Blur the top layer with Gaussian blur.

Create a layer mask on the blurred layer (the circle inside the square button next to the new layer button).

Use either a blurry brush with black fill, or create a gradient from white to black, and expose the clear layer underneath. Black reveals, white conceals.

Let me know what you think!

Comment: Gaussian blur was better option to use, however when I am applying gradient over gaussian blur, it creates a nice effect but it overlays all over the image, whereas I am trying to achieve that effect like in the link with nice blurry box with discernible borders.

Comment: Ok! All you have to do is use the rectangle marquee tool and select the area you want to be blurry (while on the mask layer), and fill the mask in white. Then hold ctrl shift I to invert the selection, and fill the rest of the mask in black. You could also just fill in the first rectangle black (leave the rest white), and then invert the mask for fewer steps @u.dzh

Comment: Awesome! If you could, just mark my answer with the check mark under the arrows, enjoy! @u.dzh

Answer (score 0):

I quess I figured out one of the good ways of how to achieve the effect:

1. I converted my image (layer 1) into the smart object
2. Created a shape with rectangle tool, with no stroke, filled with white (didn't matter what color actually as long as it's colored) (layer 2)
3. I copied the image (layer 1), and placed it on the very top (layer 3), right click, create clipping mask, go to filter, blur, gaussian blur (radius 12px)

Done!

Achieved thanks to: http://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-dynamic-ios-7-style-background-blur-in-photoshop/